# Filtering parts or all of request URL from rails logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, filter, ruby-on-rails-2

Rails provides filter_parameter_logging to filter sensitive parameters from the rails log.

If you have a a JSONP API, some sensitive information could be present in the URL.  Is there a way to filter request URLS from the log also?

Comment: For those wondering how to filter part of the *path*, here's your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65729649/1371131

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note**: The answer here was the way to get it work on Rails 2.x ~> 3.0. Starting from Rails 3.1, if you set `config.filter_parameters`, Rails will filter out the sensitive parameter in the query string as well. See [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/68802d0fbe9d20ef8c5f6626d4b3279bd3a42d3e) for more detail.

---

I think in that case, you need to override `complete_request_uri` in [ActionController::Base](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bfe032858077bb2946abe25e95e485ba6da86bd5/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L1384), since [ActionController::Benchmarking](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bfe032858077bb2946abe25e95e485ba6da86bd5/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb#L87) calls that method and prints the line that looks like:

```
Completed in 171ms (View: 35, DB: 7) | 200 OK [http://localhost:3000/]
```

I think you can put this in initializer to override this method

```
class ActionController::Base
  private

  def complete_request_uri
    "#{request.protocol}#{request.host}#{request.request_uri.gsub(/secret=([a-z0-9]+)/i, "secret=[FILTERTED]")}"
  end
end
```

Note that you need to play a bit with regular expression to make it substitute the portion you wanted.

Comment: This saved my day, thank you. I was able to simple define that function inside the controller that I wanted to filter/protect, worked great.

Comment: @nessur hey, I think this answer is quite a bit old, way way before I send a patch to fix the parameters filtering. Now, I'm pretty sure that if you set config.filter_parameters, it will also filtered out that parameter from your log. See https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/68802d0fbe9d20ef8c5f6626d4b3279bd3a42d3e and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/FilterParameters.html for detail. If not, please file a bug on Rails so I can tackle it.

Comment: thanks, but my problem is with a Rails 2.3.12 app that I'm maintaining. We have other Rails 3.2x apps where this filtering is fine, dandy. I don't think anyone's going to release more bugfixes for Rails 2.3, right? :) Cheers!

Comment: Yep, indeeeed. Then that's the way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly this no longer works in Rails 3. The path (including query parameters) comes from [ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html), which inherits from [Rack::Request](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html). Here's the relevant monkeypatch that you can throw into an initializer:

```
class ActionDispatch::Request
  def fullpath
    @fullpath ||= super.gsub(/secret=[^&]+/, 'secret=[FILTERED]')
  end
end
```

I switched to using `[^&]` in the regex since the parameter could easily have characters that aren't letters or numbers in it.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!  Was surprised to see this was not working on `rails 3.2.11`.  Hopefully this will make it into the main rails gem.