# window.open with headers

Tags: javascript, window.open

Can I control the HTTP headers sent by `window.open` (cross browser)?

If not, can I somehow `window.open` a page that then issues my request with custom headers inside its popped-up window?

I need some cunning hacks.

Comment: There is an open issue for adding support for headers to the window.open function in the HTML standard. Please voice your opinions and needs on there. [https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Can I control the HTTP headers sent by window.open (cross browser)?

No

> If not, can I somehow window.open a page that then issues my request with custom headers inside its popped-up window?

- You can request a URL that triggers a server side program which makes the request with arbitrary headers and then returns the response
- You can run JavaScript (probably saying goodbye to Progressive Enhancement) that uses XHR to make the request with arbitrary headers (assuming the URL fits within the Same Origin Policy) and then process the result in JS.

> I need some cunning hacks...

It might help if you described the problem instead of asking if possible solutions would work.

Comment: Even with XHR there is limited support for header customization (http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method)

Comment: @FreeConsulting link is actually: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method

Comment: Is this different for <a href="..." target="_blank">? That seems to preserve login status.

Comment: @sureshvv — No. You cannot control the headers sent there either. If it preserves login status that is because the login method doesn't use custom headers.

Comment: No custom headers needed. Just basic auth. How do u pass that to window.open()?

Comment: You can't. The user will be prompted to enter their credentials when they visit the URL. The browser will then remember them for the session.

Comment: @quentin ok.. i have job dashboard url within my .NET solution (so everything there is several web apps within one IIS site, including Identity server), which I access from Angular app (another web app). I am an authenticated user, however when I am redirected to dashboard url (via window.open, no other way, since it's a server page)  - there is no any authentication info available. How am I supposed to get this authentication info? Of course I am not going to expose anything via URL.

Comment: @Alexander - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 29):

Sadly you can't control headers when doing window.open()

Nice and easy, how I managed to open a file with custom headers:

```js
const viewFile = async (url) => {

  // Change this to use your HTTP client
      fetch(url, {/*YOUR CUSTOM HEADER*/} ) // FETCH BLOB FROM IT
        .then((response) => response.blob())
        .then((blob) => { // RETRIEVE THE BLOB AND CREATE LOCAL URL
          var _url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          window.open(_url, "_blank").focus(); // window.open + focus
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
};
```

- Download file to cache
- window.open to cache

Answer (score 11):

If you are in control of server side, it might be possible to set header value in query string and send it like that?
That way you could parse it from query string if it's not found in the headers.

Just an idea... And you asked for a cunning hack :)

Comment: is n't adding a header in query string is susceptible to any security issues? since it is not going to be encrypted in https.

Comment: Querystrings ARE encrypted with https. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl
But you still shouldn't put any sensitive info in query string... OP didn't  specify what kind of headers they would like to put in query string.

Answer (score 0):

As the best anwser have writed using `XMLHttpResponse` except `window.open`, and I make the abstracts-anwser as a instance.

The main Js file is `download.js` [Download-JS](https://github.com/rndme/download)

```js
 // var download_url = window.BASE_URL+ "/waf/p1/download_rules";
    var download_url = window.BASE_URL+ "/waf/p1/download_logs_by_dt";
    function download33() {
        var sender_data = {"start_time":"2018-10-9", "end_time":"2018-10-17"};
        var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open("POST", download_url, true);
        x.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
//        x.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        x.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "JWT " + localStorage.token );
        x.responseType = 'blob';
        x.onload=function(e){download(x.response, "test211.zip", "application/zip" ); }
        x.send( JSON.stringify(sender_data) ); // post-data
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use an **F5 load balancer**, and map the cross-browser URL that you are trying to fetch to an URL inside your domain of origin.

Mapping can be something like:

```
companyA.com/api/of/interest----> companyB.com/api/of/interest
```

Assuming your domain of origin is "companyA.com" then the browser will not have any problems in sending all cookies on the header of that request, since it's towards the same domain.

The request hits the load balancer and is forwarded towards "companyB.com" with all headers responses will be sent to the from server side.

Comment: The question is about "custom headers" not "cookies belonging to a different domain".

Answer (score -4):

> **You can't  directly add custom headers with *window.open()* in popup window 
>   but to work that we have two possible solutions**

---

> 1. Write Ajax method to call that particular URL with headers in a separate HTML file and use that HTML as url in`<i>window.open()</i>` 
>      here is *abc.html*

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "ORIGIONAL_URL",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            Authorization : 'Bearer ' + data.id_token,
            AuthorizationCheck : 'AccessCode ' +data.checkSum , 
            ContentType :'application/json'
        },

        success: function (result) {
              console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {

        } });
```

call html

```
window.open('*\abc.html')
```

> **here CORS policy can block the request if CORS is not enabled in requested URL**.

---

> 2. You can request a URL that triggers a server-side program which makes the request with custom headers and then returns the response redirecting to that particular url.

Suppose in Java Servlet(/requestURL) we'll make this request

`

```
        String[] responseHeader= new String[2];
        responseHeader[0] = "Bearer " + id_token;
        responseHeader[1] = "AccessCode " + checkSum;

        String url = "ORIGIONAL_URL";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", responseHeader[0]);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("AuthorizationCheck", responseHeader[1]);
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
                         InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response1 = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response1.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            response.sendRedirect(response1.toString());
            // print result
            System.out.println(response1.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("GET request not worked");
        }
```

`

call servlet in    `window.open('/requestURL')`

Answer (score -6):

### Use POST instead

Although it is easy to construct a GET query using `window.open()`, it's a bad idea (see below). One workaround is to create a form that submits a POST request. Like so:

```
<form id="helper" method="post" target="_blank" action="###/your_page###" style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" name="headerData" value="(default)">
</form>

<input type="button" onclick="loadNnextPage()" value="Click me!">

<script>
function loadNnextPage() {
  document.getElementById("helper").headerData.value = "New";
  document.getElementById("helper").submit();
}
</script>
```

Of course you will need something on the server side to handle this; as others have suggested you could create a "proxy" script that sends headers on your behalf and returns the results.

**Problems with GET**

- Query strings get stored in browser history,
- can be shoulder-surfed
- copy-pasted,
- and often you don't want it to be easy to "refresh" the same transaction.