# Launch download in the same tab without opening new tab or window in Javascript

Tags: javascript, download

I am using this javascript function to launch download

```
function startDownload(url) {
   window.open(url, 'Download');
}
```

It works, but i want to block any new tab or new window launch, thanks.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
function startDownload(url) {

    window.location.href = url;
}
```

This will start the download in the same page, exactly like when you click a link without any target other than `_self`.

To force the download of a file, make sure you send the right headers with it:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf";
```

This will make sure that the file is not displayed in the browser instead of being downloaded. Replace the filename part with the filename you want as default on the `save as` dialog.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but where do you put Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf";?

Comment: @Marcel this is likely too late but headers must be set at the destination url and cannot be set by Javascript. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4326141/810794

Comment: @Marcel , You put it in response from server. Here is java code: ```Response.ok(fileContent, "application/octet-stream").header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=mypdf.pdf").build(); ```

Comment: @vanduc1102 thank you for the code. I have had this figured out for a long time.

Comment: Super helpful!  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

`window.open` will open a new window \ tab (depending on user preferences) ... to just download the file use

```
window.location.href = url;
```

You can use this if the `url` returns a downloadable file rather than a web page

Comment: I still have probleme with internet explorer, if i have a .pdf file, it open it and i have un encrypted file on my browser. for chrome and firefox it works very well.

Comment: Where are you serving the PDF from ? what is the MIME type being sent with the PDF ? what does IE show ?

Comment: Thats what i get in IE when i launch the download
›É"¨36k.yš6¢Š(« ä÷§äš Ôø;}êÌ$‘ÍK„¯4QEóH1Ò‡$Å"ä¶*5ÞÒyŸéQEúŒœR‚¯Zšá8â¤q‘EQQàŽ¦ž¤æšsšQ‘TÆàj˜Þz(¢ŠÕÒîÌR)ÏC]Å•È•†é^qQ±].....

Comment: I am using a HttpHandler by the way

Answer (score 9):

HTML5 solution with 'download' attribute

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Definitely take a look at this https://caniuse.com/#feat=download before using this solution

Comment: The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier

Comment: Also, since it is a javascript function that is launching the download, I think that creating a link, hiding it and then sending a click event on it is a lot of work for just a one-liner javascript...

Answer (score 5):

```
<a target="_parent" href="link"></a>
```

- _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
- _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
- _self - URL replaces the current page
- _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded name - The name of the window

Comment: `_self` is the default according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target