# Can not export html table to excel using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, excel

I have around 5000 rows(tr) inside HTML table each having 10 columns(td). Now I am trying to export this whole HTML table to excel using following jQuery code:

```
var test = $('#data');
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(test.html()));
```

Have also tried with many other jQuery plugins like DataTables.net, jqWidgets and jqGrid but each time my browser gets crashed and have to reload the page again.

Comment: Try sending the data first to your application server and then set headers from your server.

Comment: Can't make use of application server as I have to implement things using client side only.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry to say but even jsFiddle also giving me same error when I tried to post HTMl data and jQuery code over there.

Comment: Perhaps this link clear you in all aspects : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325968/window-open-with-headers

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**window.open()** has its scope and limitations that has been well explained in this post: [Export to CSV using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html/16203218#16203218)

For your concern, I tested with 2500 rows and it works fine. (I can't upload so much data on jsfiddler but I am sure it will work for 5000 rows also.)

Also, I suspect if you are wrapping your html table into a container DIV. Just put your html table into a DIV and use like this -

```
$("[id$=myButtonControlID]").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=divTableDataHolder]').html()));
    e.preventDefault();   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AnilAwadh/wJyWm/

**encodeURIComponent()** is a Javascript function that is used to encode special characters if you data has any and its use is optional.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting **non-IE browsers**, try the following:

```
var test = $('#data');
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + 
            encodeURIComponent(test[0].outerHTML));
```

See it working here by using Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/56tvb/2/.

If you are targeting **Internet Explorer** as a browser, you have to look for a different approach, as the current one **will not work**. From the MSDN library, the [data Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) topic says:

> Data URIs are supported only for the following elements and/or
>   attributes.
>
> ```
> object (images only)
> img
> input type=image
> link
> CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background, backgroundImage, 
> and so on.
> ```
>
> Data URIs can be nested.
>
> For security reasons, data URIs are restricted to downloaded
>   resources. ***Data URIs cannot be used for navigation***, for scripting, or
>   to populate frame or iframe elements.

Answer (score 0):

My friend suggested this approach - try creating a blob and use navigator.msSaveBlob() or navigator. msSaveOrOpenBlob() .

```
    var csvContent=data; 
    var blob = new Blob([csvContent],{
        type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;",
    });

    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "filename.csv") 
//or navigator. msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "filename.csv")
```

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772331(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin - **tableExport.js**

**HTML:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
<body>
<tr class="noExl">
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Column heading</th>
  <th>Column heading</th>
  <th>Column heading</th>
</tr>
</body>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#table2excel").table2excel({
    // exclude CSS class
    exclude: ".noExl",
    name: "Excel Document Name"
  });
});
```

**Plugin download:** http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html