# is that possible to send header information in $window.open(url) method

Tags: angularjs

I am downloading the file from the server using API, for that i have to send session details in header, how can i do it using angularjs?. Please help me out.

Thank you in advance for suggestions.

Comment: There is an open issue for adding support for headers to the window.open function in the HTML standard. Please voice your opinions and needs on there. [https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810)

Answer (score 3):

**No** - It is not possible to send headers in straight way using `$window.open`

**Yes** - Its is possible but not straight way, If you've got server-side control then you can set `header` value in query string and get it parsed from query string on the back-end.

Answer (score 2):

I don't suggest to pass params with window.open.

BUT you can use window.open like this.

```
var params = {
 access_token: 'An access_token',
 other_header: 'other_header'
};

//Add authentication headers in URL
var url = [url_generating_pdf, $.param(params)].join('?');

//Open window
window.open(url);
```

Please check the details info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138671/how-to-add-authentication-header-to-window-open)

Comment: Nope, didn't work for me.  This just appends the values I want in my header into the URL string.  It's not the same thing.

Comment: Do not put tokens in URL- that's insecure https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141515/4233629