# Redirect to external site, passing Authorization header

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I route a user to another web site from my Angular application using `$window.open(url, '')`.  Currently they are directed to the login page but now there is a requirement for single sign on so the user can access the external site if they are logged in to my application.  The external site has asked that I send a JavaScript Web Token in the Authorisation Header using the Bearer schema when I redirect the user.

How can I set the Authorization header in Angular when sending a user to anther site.  I've only ever used the header in the context of communicating with an API (`$http.get()`), rather than sending the user elsewhere.  I don't think `$window.open` has any means to do this so I might need to use something else.

Although this question is similar, the answer describes sending the token as a get parameter in the URL.  The Authorization header is not used. [how to add authentication header to $window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138671/how-to-add-authentication-header-to-window-open)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add authentication header to $window.open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138671/how-to-add-authentication-header-to-window-open)

Comment: @stefchri That question sends the token in the url rather than as a header.  That won't work here as I have no control over the destination.  I need to use the bearer schema.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No. Instead I make a separate HTTP GET request setting the header, and the external site returns an authentication cookie which is set on the client. Then I redirect the user without a header.  The third party application had to accommodate that as we didn't manage to set the header on a redirect.