# Authorization of an api to get data in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, cors, token

I have an API to get the data I have to put Authorization in header but it didn't work. Here is the image in postman

https://drive.google.com/open?id=18CY4uBc83u9AcN9Uu2SFXMjPgc4FPBzU

[image]

I have applied this question answer 
[AngularJS Adding a header to the $http.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102102/angularjs-adding-a-header-to-the-http-get)
But it didn't work.

**HTML:-**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="getApiData()">
  GET DATA
</button>
```

**JS:-**

```
$scope.getApiData = function(){
    $http({
      method  : 'GET',
      url     : 'http://api.getlokalapp.com/posts/7678/?format=json',
      headers : {
        'Content-Type'  : 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : '5ae5f64653ce85803b44b7b6f4d216c2dae02251'
      }
    })
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

I want the output is response as it is shown in postman request but I am unable to get it please help me to get the data from the API.

Error message which I am getting is-

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://api.getlokalapp.com/posts/7678/?format=json' from origin
>   'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

But I have integrated other APIs and there I didn't get any error.

Comment: This problem is from the API provider's side. You can't do anything except asking them to fix this and allow you to use their API, since it is blocked by CORS (Cross Origin) policy.

Comment: Thanks @VermaJr. for your feedback and my code is correct if you see the gdrive link and my code do you think is there any bug for Authorization of the value

Comment: Your code looks fine. This problem is definitely from their side. Is their API available for public use?

Comment: No this is for company api i have to check with my team

Comment: If it is not available for public use, then is a very normal error because the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You just **cannot** access their API using JavaScript then.

Comment: is it blocking your local requests or even when you deploy at server do they have whitelisting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fix this in your production code unless the API provider adds `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in their backend. In order to just check if your code is working and to see the results, in Windows, paste this command in Run (Windows + R) window.

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

And for Mac,

```
$ open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

This will open a new Chrome instance which will grant you access to this API, bypassing browser security.

Comment: can you tell me the command for mac

Comment: This command didn't bypass the browser security

Comment: finally CORS issue was resolved from the backed only