# Set Accepts in HTTP Request to window.open javascript call

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I have a window.open command like this:

```
window.open("http://MyServer/MyPage");
```

And I know that I can set `accepts` of a request, using something like this:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "http://MyServer/MyPage");
client.setRequestHeader("Accept", "ContentTypeName");
client.send();
```

Now I need to combine this two things. But I don't know how.
So...

**How can I set accepts in HTTP header to a call executed by a window.open command?**

**UPDATED**
Here is a very similar question to that: [window.open with headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4325968/1233788).
And is already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326141/1233788).

But as the answer suggests I write in my new window, will be not possible if my content type is a binary like:

- application/pdf
- application/vnd.ms-excel
- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

That for my needs these types will be present. So anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: What you COULD do is to document.write the result of an AJAX call (with request headers set) to the new window

Comment: Because my content type in many cases is excel or pdf and I can't write this.

Comment: Why not request `/?format=pdf` or /pdf/... and have the server generate the content type?

Comment: Yeah it's possible, but just for curiosity, I want to know if it's possible using accepts parameter.

Comment: The computer says no... [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453415.aspx)

Comment: I edited the question, can you re-evaluate the duplicate markup?

Comment: The answer is still `not possible` - however in some browsers you were able to pass the mime type to the document.open, so in principle you could try: `var win=window.open(); win.document.open("application/excel"); win.document.write(excelData); win.document.close()`