# Using AngularJS $location and set a Header

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a reconnect to another site on my server.

Currently using `$location.url('http://127.0.0.1/second');` to forward to the second site, but I need to set the `Authorization` Header to a custom variable.

I searched through the `$http` and `$location` documentation on [docs.angularjs.org](http://docs.angularjs.org), but I wasn't able to find anything helpful.

Comment: has nothing to do with angular. There's no way to set headers for redirect other than basic auth in url

Comment: How can I do it else? I need to set the header and need a recreate. I don't want to pass it via a GET param

Comment: you can't , it's a request initiated by the browser itself, not by any code. Even using window.open you can't  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325968/window-open-with-headers

Comment: One way to do this is with an nginx (or apache) proxy that allows access to the 2nd site (by either adding the header or bypassing it altogether based on referrer). But that begs the question what is the point of the custom Auth header if you are just bypassing it without asking the user for it? What is the value of the variable? Is it user supplied or some kind of token?

Comment: It is a token. So nothing user supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use `$http`;

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://127.0.0.1/second', headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic Key'}
});
```

For more [INFO](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)...

Comment: Okey I though $http just makes a request like in NodeJS.

Comment: It doesn't. This is also just a request, which returns data. I need a forwarding with set headers. The 2nd site needs to be displayed!