# Possible way to add headers in a window.open request

Tags: javascript, browser, http-headers, window, request-headers

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325968/window-open-with-headers)  says I can't pass headers while using window.open. Although I couldn't find any documentation stating this.

Is it really not possible to do so. Are there any possible hacks ?

My client requests are sent to a server which I can't control. The request sent by browser for opening pdf (`window.open`) is received at that server without `auth` headers. Hence, user is prompted for username and password.

Is there a way I can resolve my issue and be able to open pdf from my Angular application. I would also like to know how `window.open` works internally as I could not find it online ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The spec does not give any clue that this is intended, though query parameters are also some kind of header... https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.open with headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325968/window-open-with-headers)

Comment: I do not have access to server, hence cannot use above solutions

Comment: There is an open issue for adding support for headers to the window.open function in the HTML standard. Please voice your opinions and needs on there. [https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the problem by getting the file twice, once from the server and once from cache.  This required a Cache-Control header on the response.  I'm working with Angular, AdalJS, and Web Api but this might apply more broadly.

I use a $http call with auth header added by AdalJS to securely retrieve the file.  This response is cached by the browser.  When complete, I use window.open to open the cached file.

Pop-up blocking can be a problem.  If you can't disable blocking, consider displaying a second button to click when the download is complete, calling window.open from that.