# Open a link in current tab with modified headers

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ajax, typescript

Here, in my angular project I am trying to open a link via button where it redirects to the link, by using this:

```
window.open(MY_LINK, "_self");
```

In this scenario, I also want to pass an access token in the header when I click the link. I do not want to pass on the access token to the parameter, obviously because of the security purpose.

Is there any way I can achieve this?
Any help would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Akhil but it's not possible to add headers and use it with window.open

For some ideas, I give you this reference [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326141/10310278)