# Are HTTPS URLs secure?

Tags: url, https, security, stripe-payments

If a website makes a GET request, from a HTTPS page to another HTTPS page, is that secure? Specifically, is the data in the URL / query params secure?

I'm asking because, hen I call Stripe.createToken, a connection is made to a URL with the credit card number in it.  Even though the query parameter says _method=POST, it is being transmitted over a GET query param:

```
Request URL: https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens?card[number]=4242424242424242&card[cvc]=123&card[exp_month]=4&card[exp_year]=2016&key=pk_test_1236&callback=sjsonp11234&_method=POST
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Now, I understand this is all over HTTPS, but isn't the URL part insecure?  I thought that URLs get logged in various places along the way to their destination.

Comment: This might be a better fit for: http://security.stackexchange.com/ since there is not a specific programming issue (that I can see anyway).

Comment: @Jeff, did you figure out how to get those parameters out of the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URLs usually do get logged in webserver logs. It is a very bad idea to sent that information as part of a GET request. The hops a request takes between the client and the destination *are* encrypted though. So assuming there is no web proxy or anything the only place it might be logged is on `https://api.stripe.com/`'s webserver.

See [Are querystring parameters secure in HTTPS (HTTP + SSL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl)
 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

From Stripe:

> Because of the nature of how HTTPS works, the only information that's transmitted in plaintext to an HTTPS connection is the hostname you're connecting to (in this case, "api.stripe.com"). All other parts of the communication - including the full URL - are encrypted such that they're only decryptable by our servers. At the transport level, including cardholder details as GET parameters of the URL is no different from including them in the POST body. We only use JSONP for Stripe.js and not for any server-side bindings, in case you are worried about having those requests come up in your server logs.
>
> Once the details get to our server, we've made changes to the configurations on our servers to ensure that the query strings are never logged, and we have routines in place that check all log files for accidental inclusion of card numbers. We've worked with our PCI auditors (who also audit Google, Apple and AWS) to ensure that this meets the standards of PCI, and are confident that we're handling cardholder data in a way that is secure.