# Is it possible to pass Facebook Graph API access token through request header?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am testing Facebook Graph API v2.3 with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).
While it is possible to get response by putting access token in query string as follow:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?access_token=my_access_token
```

I am wondering whether it's possible to do the same thing with HTTP request headers, which would be something like this:

```
GET /v2.3/me HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
Authorization: <my_access_token>
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: <postman_token>
```

Based on this similar question (i.e. [How should a client pass a facebook access token to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526211/how-should-a-client-pass-a-facebook-access-token-to-the-server)) on Stackoverflow, it seems that this should be possible.

Any thoughts on this?

---

### Edit:

> What raised my interest is that, when I used the `API Graph Explorer` provided by Facebook Developers, it seems that there's no query string in that sandbox either. How does that work?

`Facebook API Graph Explorer` DO use query string for access token. Thanks to [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe)'s response.

Comment: Of course Graph API Explorer passes the access token as a query string parameter (for GET requests), you can clearly see that when you look at the request it makes in your browser’s developer tools network panel.

Comment: @CBroe I think you are right. After checking the Network panel it's clear that Graph API Explorer passes the access token using query string. Does that mean query string is the only way to pass it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes it is possible

```
Authorization: Bearer AccessTokenHere
```

e.g.

`curl --header "Authorization: Bearer CAAC...ZD" https://graph.facebook.com/me`

<sub>This answer previously recommended using "OAuth" instead of "Bearer" as the [token type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-7.1). Both will work, but "Bearer" is the type that shows up in the standard. Also, on completing Facebook's OAuth flow, the `token_type` in their response is `bearer`. So all in all "Bearer" makes more sense.</sub>

Comment: Brilliant!! I just missed out the "OAuth" in front of the access token. Thank you @phwd

Comment: Is this documented somewhere on Facebook?

Comment: @phwd Thank you. It wasn't clear to me that Facebook's API was OAuth compliant (but it makes sense).