# FOSOAuthServerBundle: Embed the access_token in the Authorization header

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, fosoauthserverbundle

From what I can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl), it isn't a good idea to hold sensitive data (like an access_token) in querystring parameters.

i.e: I am trying to avoid this:

```
http://localhost.dev/web/app_dev.php/api/articles?access_token=NzJhNz.....
```

Therefore, I tried to make api requests with the `access_token` in the Authorization header (which was suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/symfony2/28LvLvZPpx0/E97WRkY3hzIJ). 
When trying to do so, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "OAuth2 authentication required"
}
```

However, the request is exactly like this, and the token seems to be properly set:

```
GET /web/app_dev.php/api/articles HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost.dev
Authorization   access_token=N2FmNzhhNGM2MTI5N2JhMWJlYjEdZjA0ZWM3ZTRhMTM1OGM0ODJjMzQzYjM7NTk3ZTEzNTVjZDczZTljMDk2MQ
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept  application/json
Accept-Language en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
User-Agent  Localhost/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 6.1.4; Scale/2.00)
```

Does anyone one know if this is possible with `FOSOAuthServerBundle`?

***Note:*** I verified in the browser, and the token is still valid (not expired).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/issues/185) by [@alanbem](https://github.com/alanbem), the **Authorization Header** should look like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer N2FmNzhhNGM2MTI5N2JhMWJlYj...
```

***Note:*** If you're using `AFHTTPClient` for iOS development, you simply have to override the `(void)setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:(NSString *)token` method.

```c
- (void)setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:(NSString *)token {
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", token]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Mick, you can use the Authorization header.

If you are doing it internally, inside PHPUnit and any other place that uses a Symfony Request, you should use the header like:

```
$headers = ['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => 'Bearer  2FmNzhhNGM2MTI5N2JhMWJlYj...'];
```

It's important when you are testing and don't want to mess your URI or Request params.