# Passing value from simple text box with no Submit button to the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In an existing code, I already had this in my view:

```
<p class="label">@Html.ActionLink("Update Your Email", "UpdateEmail", "Settings")<br/>
```

And I added a simple text box there so they can type their password. Please note that I **DO NOT** want a submit button or anything more, just a text box to type their password.

```
<input type="password" name="userpassword"/>
```

And in the `controller` for the action in that `ActionLink` I currently from old code I have this:

```
public ActionResult UpdateEmail()
{
    // I just want to have the password they typed in here to use it. 
    // some pre-existing stuff
}
```

How can I do this? When I come to `UpdateEmail()` I want to know what did they type in the `textbox`?  Sorry I am noob and stupid question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is how manager and designer wanted it.  am not arguing that. Sorry.

Comment: @StephenMuecke OMG Why are you arguing so much with me, maybe in real code it is not a password and it is their dog name! I can't post exact code of company here! so simpliied it to what you see .

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, my understanding is that HTTPS as opposed to HTTP is the relevant factor, not whether it's POST body or GET querystring. If it's HTTPS, everything else other than the domain is encrypted.

Comment: I'm not arguing. I'm trying to understand what you want to do! If you want to redirect to a GET method, use a form with `method="get"` and submit the value(s) to a method which has parameters for the values your posting. Other wise use javascript to update the `href` parameter of the link. But the normal approach is to submit a form to a POST method

Comment: @David you said to Stephen " ... my understanding is that HTTPS as opposed to HTTP is the relevant factor, not whether it's POST body or GET querystring. If it's HTTPS, everything else other than the domain is encrypted." Here is a [good read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2629241) ... in particular the 2 obvious places where the data is *not* encrypted

Comment: And whatever was deleted in comments above from @StephenMuecke might have been an attempt to look out for your best interest. But it is now gone. Remember, we work for free here.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the link! I didn't consider the issue of server logs, and that SO post led me to this: http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/

Comment: @David what is potentially more troubling is the possibility of, say, a co-worker replaying or running off with your browser cache (or shell cache). No one is talking shell here, but the same concept applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot determine what they typed in the box, until the information is POSTed to an action of some sort. You already have one Action method defined:

```
public ActionResult UpdateEmail() {}
```

You need another method defined:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateEmail([FromBody] ViewModelType viewModel) {}
```

where `ViewModelType` is defined as having a public property with a public `userpassword` field. You should also consider adding an `[HttpGet]` annotation to your existing `UpdateEmail()` method.

Comment: well the scenario is they type something in that textbox, then they click on that update email link that used to be there from before. So now does your solution work? I need a little more explanation to understand it. Thanks

Comment: In that case, yes, but you definitely need a click event handler on the link, to read the textbox and trigger the POST to UpdateEmail(viewmodel). (And it should be a POST instead of a GET, because you're making a change.)