# cURL -d . parameter

Tags: curl

I have this curl command:

```
curl -k -d . -o SessionRequest.txt 
"https://myserver.com/MyWebApi/user?companysn=1234&login=my_login&password=my_password&ApiKey=my_api_key"
```

What does `-d .` stand for? What does it do?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Whenever your have a doubt use `man`.

Issue `man curl` and read about `-d` switch.

```
-d, --data <data>
    (HTTP)  Sends  the  specified data in a POST request to the HTTP
    cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type
    -d, --data is the same as --data-ascii. --data-raw is almost the
    ter.  To  post  data  purely  binary, you should instead use the
    [...]
```

It allows you to send ASCII data, eg.:

```
curl -d '{"hello": "world"}' -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://example.com
```

Send a JSON string to the server.

In your example, it just send a `.` character as ASCII data to the server. What it does depends on the server logic and is out of the `curl` command scope.

This said, we can guess what a `.` (dot, period, full stop) might mean in computer science:

- Dot is a placeholder for the current directory in Unix File Systems;
- Dot is a wildcard for any character in most Regular Expression grammars;
- Dot is the separator between labels in domain name;
- Dot is a common separator for filename and extension;

*Nota:* It is considered as a bad practice to send credentials using `GET` parameters, [avoid it if you can and read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl).

Comment: I did read the man page but could not understand anything. I still cant understand what the "." does.

Comment: The "." does nothing magic. It is a text "." that will be sent as data.

Comment: @EricObermühlner, indeed this is out of scope of curl command. This is delegated to the server logic behind. Curl is just the middleman.

Comment: Using a bash session to a Debian 9 (stretch) instance, I use `curl --help` to get the help documentation

Comment: Note that `-d` w/o any header passes `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header implicitly so you might get surprising result based on how you're passing value to `-d`

Comment: @shriek that's freaking important, thanks for pointing it out