# troubles generating signature for alibaba cloud

Tags: alibaba-cloud

Reading the [HTTP API docs](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25492.htm). My requests fail though for bad signature. From error message I can see that my string to sign is correct but looks like I can't generate the correct HMAC-SHA1 (seriously why use SHA1 still??).

So I decided to try replicate the signature of the sample inside same document.

```
[47] pry(main)> to_sign = "GET&%2F&AccessKeyId%3Dtestid&Action%3DDescribeRegions&Format%3DXML&SignatureMethod%3DHMAC-SHA1&SignatureNonce%3D3ee8c1b8-83d3-44af-a94f-4e0ad82fd6cf&SignatureVersion%3D1.0&Timestamp%3D2016-02-23T12%253A46%253A24Z&Version%3D2014-05-26"

[48] pry(main)> Base64.encode64 OpenSSL::HMAC.digest("sha1", "testsecret", to_sign)
=> "MLAxpXej4jJ7TL0smgWpOgynR7s=\n"

[49] pry(main)> Base64.encode64 OpenSSL::HMAC.digest("sha1", "testsecret&", to_sign)
=> "VyBL52idtt+oImX0NZC+2ngk15Q=\n"

[50] pry(main)> Base64.encode64 OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest("sha1", "testsecret&", to_sign)
=> "NTcyMDRiZTc2ODlkYjZkZmE4MjI2NWY0MzU5MGJlZGE3ODI0ZDc5NA==\n"

[51] pry(main)> Base64.encode64 OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest("sha1", "testsecret", to_sign)
=> "MzBiMDMxYTU3N2EzZTIzMjdiNGNiZDJjOWEwNWE5M2EwY2E3NDdiYg==\n"

[52] pry(main)> OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest("sha1", "testsecret&", to_sign)
=> "57204be7689db6dfa82265f43590beda7824d794"

[53] pry(main)> OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest("sha1", "testsecret", to_sign)
=> "30b031a577a3e2327b4cbd2c9a05a93a0ca747bb"
```

As evident none of these matches the example signature of `CT9X0VtwR86fNWSnsc6v8YGOjuE=`. Any idea what is missing here?

**Update:** taking `tcpdump` from the Golang client tool I see that it does a `POST` request like:

```
POST /?AccessKeyId=**********&Action=DescribeRegions&Format=JSON&RegionId=cn-qingdao&Signature=aHZVpIMb0%2BFKdoWSIVaFJ7bd2LA%3D&SignatureMethod=HMAC-SHA1&SignatureNonce=c29a0e28964c470a8997aebca4848b57&SignatureType=&SignatureVersion=1.0&Timestamp=2018-07-16T19%3A46%3A33Z&Version=2014-05-26 HTTP/1.1

    Host: ecs.aliyuncs.com
    User-Agent: Aliyun-CLI-V3.0.3
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    x-sdk-client: golang/1.0.0
    x-sdk-core-version: 0.0.1
    x-sdk-invoke-type: common
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

When I take parameters from the above request and generate signature it **does** match. So I tried all tree: `GET`, `POST` with URL params and `POST` with params in body. Every time I am getting a signature error. If I redo the request with exact same params as the golang tool, I'm getting nonce already used error (as expected).

Comment: did you solved it ? i'm having the same issue

Comment: @RickyLevi, yes, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this working. The main issue in my case was that I have been double-percent-encoding the signature parameter thus it turned out invalid. What helped me most was running the `aliyun` cli utility and capturing traffic, then running a query with exactly the same parameters to compare the exact query string.

But let me list some key points for me:

1. once hmac-sha1 sig is generated, do not percent-encode it, just add it to the query with normal form www encoding
2. order of parameters in the HTTP query is not significant; order of parameters in the signing string **is** significant though
3. I find all the following types of requests to work: GET, POST with parameters in URL query, POST with parameters in request body form www encoded; I'm using GET per documentation but I see [aliyun](https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-cli) using POST vs query params and ordered params in the query
4. you must add `&` character to the end of the secret key when generating HMAC-SHA1
5. generate HMAC-SHA1 in binary form, then encode as Base64 (no hex values)
6. some parameters might be case insensitive, e.g. `Format` works both as `json` and `JSON`
7. I see [aliyun](https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-cli), @wanghq and [John](https://www.neoprime.io/info/alibaba/devops/day_05.php) using UUID 4 for SignatureNonce but I deferred to plain random (according to docs) because it seems to be only a replay attack protection. So cryptographically secure random number must unnecessary.
8. The special encoding rules for `+`, `*` and `~` seem to only apply to string for signing, not actually to encode data in such a way in the HTTP query.

I decided to not use @wanghq's wrapper as it didn't work for me as well [disables certificate validation](https://github.com/Lax/aliyun/issues/8) but maybe it's going to be fixed. Just I thought that queries are simple enough once signature is figured out and an additional layer of indirection is not worth it. +1 to his answer though as it was helpful to get my signature right.

Here's example ruby code to make a simple request:

```rb
require 'base64'
require 'cgi'
require 'openssl'
require 'time'
require 'rest-client'

# perform a request against Alibaba Cloud API
# @see https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25489.htm
def request(action:, params: {})
  api_url = "https://ecs.aliyuncs.com/"

  # method = "POST"
  method = "GET"
  process_params!(http: method, action: action, params: params)
  RestClient::Request.new(method: method, url: api_url, headers: {params: params})
  # RestClient::Request.new(method: method, url: api_url, payload: params)
  # RestClient::Request.new(method: method, url: api_url, payload: params.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{CGI.escape(v)}"}.join("&"))
end

# generates the required common params for a request and adds them to params
# @return undefined
# @see https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25490.htm
def process_params!(http:, action:, params:)
  params.merge!({
    "Action" => action,
    "AccessKeyId" => config[:auth][:key_id],
    "Format" => "JSON",
    "Version" => "2014-05-26",
    "Timestamp" => Time.now.utc.iso8601
  })
  sign!(http: http, action: action, params: params)
end

# generate request signature and adds to params
# @return undefined
# @see https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25492.htm
def sign!(http:, action:, params:)
  params.delete "Signature"
  params["SignatureMethod"] = "HMAC-SHA1"
  params["SignatureVersion"] = "1.0"
  params["SignatureNonce"] = "#{rand(1_000_000_000_000)}"
  # params["SignatureNonce"] = SecureRandom.uuid.gsub("-", "")

  canonicalized_query_string = params.sort.map { |key, value|
    "#{key}=#{percent_encode value}"
  }.join("&")

  string_to_sign = %{#{http}&#{percent_encode("/")}&#{percent_encode(canonicalized_query_string)}}

  params["Signature"] = hmac_sha1(string_to_sign)
end

# @param data [String]
# @return [String]
def hmac_sha1(data, secret: config[:auth][:key_secret])
  Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha1', "#{secret}&", data)).strip
end

# encode strings per Alibaba cloud rules for signing
# @return [String] encoded string
# @see https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25492.htm
def percent_encode(str)
  CGI.escape(str).gsub(?+, "%20").gsub(?*, "%2A").gsub("%7E", ?~)
end

## example call
request(action: "DescribeRegions")
```

Code can be simplified a little but decided to keep it very close to documentation instructions.

P.S. not sure why John deleted his answer but leaving a link above to his web page for any python guys looking for example code

Comment: don't know ... keep getting `IncompleteSignature` ...

Comment: @RickyLevi, I would suggest you to run wireshark and check what your code generates vs cli for the same request. This will help you with both - code issues and setup issues.

Answer (score 1):

- Seems this [aliyun ruby sdk](https://github.com/Lax/aliyun) (non official, just for reference) works. You may want to check [how it's implemented](https://github.com/Lax/aliyun/blob/master/lib/aliyun/common.rb#L80-L106).
- Check how its string_to_sign looks like. I did a run and seems it's slightly different than what you provided. The params are concatenated with `&` instead of `%26`.
  `GET&%2F&AccessKeyId%3Dtestid&Action%3DDescribeRegions&Format%3DXML&SignatureMethod%3DHMAC-SHA1&SignatureNonce%3D3ee8c1b8-83d3-44af-a94f-4e0ad82fd6cf&SignatureVersion%3D1.0&Timestamp%3D2016-02-23T12%253A46%253A24Z&Version%3D2014-05-26`

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'aliyun'

    $DEBUG = true

    options = {
      :access_key_id => "k",
      :access_key_secret => "s",
      :service => :ecs
    }

    service = Aliyun::Service.new options

    puts service.DescribeRegions({})
```

Comment: @JohnHanley why it's insecure? Can you describe the exact problem?

Comment: But only the client and server can see it and none in the middle can see it. Are you worrying about the client, server, or anything between the two? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl

Comment: @JohnHanley, "lookup the internet" is not a valid argument. While GET is somehow ugly for the purpose looking at exact request requirements, I don't see any obvious way to exploit (unless non-tls connection is used in which case things are already hopeless). Please list the specific issues you see.

Comment: The signature created by the ruby lib matches what I have as my first example `[48]`. Funnily though, running the lib, I'm getting the same signature incomplete error. On the other hand the official Go cli tool does work with the keys I'm providing. Short of using HTTP and capture the traffic of the Go cli tool I'm out of ideas :/
@JohnHanley, `GET` is just a word. You can even have request body with a GET call even though it is not mandated by any respectable specification. I've read questions about GET call and there are no treats I can see if things are implemented according to ali docs.

Comment: And now this is really depressing. With the ruby lib I did a number of tries. And one succeeded. All the rest failed with the same incomplete signature message. While Go cli tool works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

wanted to share a library I found (`Python`) that does everything for me w/o the need to sign the request myself.
It can also help those who wants to just copy their functions and still construct the signature on their own

I'm using this:

```
from aliyunsdkcore.client import AcsClient
from aliyunsdkvpc.request.v20160428.DescribeEipAddressesRequest import DescribeEipAddressesRequest

client = AcsClient(access_key, secret_key, region)
request = DescribeEipAddressesRequest()
request.set_accept_format('json')

response = client.do_action_with_exception(request) # FYI returned as Bytes
print(response)
```

Each section in Alibaba Cloud has its own library (just like I used: `aliyunsdkvpc` for EIP addresses)
And they are all listed here:
https://develop.aliyun.com/tools/sdk?#/python