# Can HTTP request from Java be viewed /inspected in the brower

Tags: java, http

I am making an HTTP request from Java using

`HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();`

The library used is  `org.apache.http.client`

For some reason, the body tag in HttpPost is empty when it reaches the endpoint. (RequestParameters).To me, this is a separate Stack Overflow question. I had to send the request by querystring.

The query string parameters contain the username/password credentials as it request for a token. I am afraid the credentials will be visible as it is done over a query string though request will go over HTTPS (and HTTPS is encrypted). But I would have been less concerned if the request was POST with a payload.

I don't want anyone to view this request i.e the browser comes to my mind. The HTTP request does not show on the address bar or in Chrome Inspect (Network tab).

Nevertheless, **can Apache HTTP requests done from Java, in theory, be inspected by browser?  (regardless of POST with payload or querystring)**

Comment: I'm confused, are you using Java's `HttpURLConnection` or Apache's `HttpClient`(3/4)?. The latter one would be able to log raw requests and response via configuring logback i.e. with `<logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="debug"/>`

Comment: Btw. [query parameters sent over a HTTPS connections are encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl) as well, and thus not visible in a man-in-the-middle attack, though it is still not good practice to add security relevant stuff to query parameters, i.e. do avoid passing credentials on copying URLs via insecure channels (unencrypted mails, links on pages, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No, in my knowledge. You will be able to view the requests originating from the browser tab in developer tools.

If you want to see the network calls originating from your whole system, you can use tools like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Comment: So if Joe has Charles Proxy on his system and logs in to my webapplication(www.mywebapp.com/login),  he can then see, his username and password being sent over an HTTP request for a token?

Comment: you will be able to see the request, response, header contents etc.

Comment: You can try it out.